# Эффект набора текста

Tags: java, android, textview

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода текста с эффектом "набора текста", то.е. нужно,дабы появляющаяся во вьюшке надпись "Пони захватывают твой разум" выглядела так, будто бы ее медленно набирают на клавиатуре. Слышал, что есть некий атрибут для этого, но проштудировав 40 минут гугл так и не нашел ответа. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: `Thread` + `Handler`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать вот это сторонее решение: [HTextView](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView)

Оно умеет то что вам нужно плюс много чего ещё.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Подключаем в gradle:

```
compile 'hanks.xyz:htextview-library:0.1.5'
```

2. Добавляем в разметку:

```
<com.hanks.htextview.HTextView
   xmlns:htext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/text"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:background="#000000"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   htext:animateType="typer"/>
```

3. Находим в коде и анимируем

```
hTextView = (HTextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
hTextView.animateText("Слава библиотекам!"); // animate
```

---

Либо посмотрите как подобное реализовано [тут](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/6462294)

Comment: Благодарю, Юрий! Это от части помогло. Однако, можно-ли с использованием этой библиотеки управлять скоростью текста на лету? И как можно сделать проверку на полный ввод? Надеюсь, я не пропустил это мимо глаз :Д

Comment: @ИгорьЯценко, вроде бы там такого нет. Попробуйте ещё поискать подобные либы (я лично сомневаюсь что найдётся совсем готовое решение) или допилите функционал имеющейся или код по ссылке в конце ответа