# Как можно реализовать новостную бегущую строку

Tags: java, android

Перепробовал все варианты с TextView и marquee, с анимациями, ни один вариант не сработал корректно. С WebView попробовал, он зависает.

Вот как это выглядет:

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_up);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(screenWidth, -screenWidth, 0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(25000);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    mTicker.startAnimation(animation);
```

Как можно реализовать новостную бегущую строку как [этот](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html) на jQuery, посмотрел на jQuery очень много плагинов. Как на телевидении снизу, фон черный, текст белый. Может есть библиотеки или может кто подскажет как это сделать?

Comment: А как это выглядит?

Comment: Обновил........

Comment: ТЗ у вас средней подробности и понятности. Попробуйте либу отсюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600881/17609

Comment: Ну а вообще... Берёте TextView, пихаете в него нужный текст, и запускаете translate анимацию.

Comment: Да, в том то и дело что при движении подтормаживает если с анимацией

Comment: Ну... Вроде нечему тормозить... Должно работать нормально

Comment: Может потому что на фоне видео играет?

Comment: Вполне возможно. Попробуйте переместить в разметке